# Auto save in fluent nhibernate does not work

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I have a problem.
When I try to insert an object with the type book to the DB,
It should add the author also to the authors table if it doesnt exist.
Instead I get an error 'unsaved object' and the object has not been saved.
whats the problem?

the code:

```
Book:
            Id(x => x.ID);
            Map(x => x.Title);
            References(x => x.Author)
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Column("Author_id");

Author:
            Id(x => x.ID);
            Map(x => x.FullName);
```

Comment: What is the mapping? From what u said it seems to be a problem with ID mapping or some cascade

Comment: @user1430430 you're getting that error because the author does not exist in the database. Author is really the root entity so you should save the author object first

Comment: it does exist in the db.if I add the author manually it does work and if i get it from the db it has the author object.what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
References(x => x.Author)
    .Not.LazyLoad()
    .Cascade.All()         // unsaved Authors should also be saved
    .Column("Author_id");
```

don't forget you have to use `session.Get`/`session.Load` to get existing Authors

Comment: does not work!Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [Library.Author#1] what can i do?

Comment: did you use the same session to get the author and to save the book? when not use `session.Lock(author, LockMode.None);`

Comment: I did it in generic type...so i cannot use it....there is maybe another option?evertything is mapping correctly.thank u !!

Comment: the best option is to load it with the same session you use to save the book since this is the UnitOfWork(session)

Comment: how can it be possible?and if the program is shut down...i see that the save shuold be auto and i cannot understant y not